AutoRig-Pro bendy bones issue
I am using autorig-pro addon for rigging and I've encountered issue with bendy bones deformation. After even a slight movement the mesh kinda snaps to create the arc shape which is useless for animators since movement is not fluid and the deformation looks broken. I was wondering if anyone happens to have similar expirience with autorig or if its perpahp more Blender issue ? I am pretty new to Blender rigging so there is a high chance that I just dont know how exactly Blender operates the bbendy.
